# compiling a program to run in DOS mode

Tags: c++, dos

I write a simple program, to run in DOS mode. Everything works under emulated console in Win XP / Vista / Seven, but not in DOS. The error says: `this program caonnot be run in DOS mode`. I wonder is that a problem with compiler flags or something bigger.

For programming i use Code::Blocks v 8.02 with such settings for compilation:

-Wall -W -pedantic -pedantic-errors

in Project \ Build options \ Compiler settings

I've tried a clean DOS mode, booting from cd, and also setting up DOS in Virtual Machine. The same error appears.

Should i turn on some more compiler flags ? Some specific 386 / 486 optimizations ?

**UPDATE**

Ok, i've downloaded, installed and configured DJGPP. Even resolved some problems with libs and includes. Still have two questions.

**1)** i can't compile a code, which calls `_strdate` and `_strtime`, i've double checked the includes, as MSDN says it needs `time.h`, but still error says: `_strdate was not declared in this scope`, i even tried to add std::_strdate, but then i have 4, not 2 errors sazing the same

**2)** the 2nd code is about `gotoxy`, it looks like that:

```
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  COORD position;
  position.X = x; position.Y = y;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), position);
}
```

error says there is no windows.h, so i've put it in place, but then there are many more errors saying some is missing from windows.h, **I SUPPOSE** it won't work because this functions is strictly for windows right ? is there any way to write similar `gotoxy` for DOS ?

**UPDATE2**

**1)** solved using `time();` instead of `_strdate();` and `_strtime();` here's the code

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer [20];

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

strftime (buffer,80,"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S\0",timeinfo);
string myTime(buffer);
```

It now compiles under DJGPP.

**UPDATE3**

<strike>Still need to solve a code using `gotoxy`</strike> - replaced it with some other code that compiles (under DJGPP).

Thank You **all** for help. Just learnt some new things about compiling (flags, old IDE's like DJGPP, OpenWatcom) and refreshed memories setting DOS to work :--)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you build it as a DOS executable, it won't run on 64-bit Windows, since it'll be a 16-bit executable and 64-bit Windows doesn't include the 16-bit NTVDM system which is used to run the DOS executables.

Comment: It doesn't matter, i just need to run it in strict DOS environment.

Comment: trying removing every line of `#include <windows.h>` and being sure that DJGPP is compiling 16 bit code and non-PE .exe files. Also, I'd suggest something more like SDCC for 8086 programming because DJGPP sucks really bad.

Comment: Can You elaborate a little on "DJGPP sucks really bad" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the sound of things, you're currently compiling a Windows console program. Even though it's a console program, it still needs Windows to run.

To compile a program to run on real DOS, you'll need to find a (probably really old) compiler and (especially) linker that targets DOS and can produce DOS MZ executables. The last Microsoft compiler to target MS-DOS was VC++ 1.52c. If memory serves, Borland continued to target DOS somewhat later, up through something like Broland C++ 5 or so.

I believe if you check the Digital Mars web site, he may still have a C++ compiler available that targets DOS. Otherwise, you're going to be stuck looking for something used and quite old.

Edit: looking at other answers reminded me of DJGPP and OpenWatcom. My apologies for not mentioning them previously.

Be aware that from a C++ viewpoint, Borland and Microsoft are really old compilers -- they don't do namespaces at all, and template support varies from nonexistent in the Microsoft compiler to mediocre in Borland's. DJGPP is basically a DOS extender to which gcc has been ported; the degree to which it's out of date (or modern) will depend on which version of gcc is involved. The Digital Mars compiler is somewhat more modern than the Borland one if I'm not mistaken, but Walter Bright now spends most of his time working on D instead of C++, so the C++ compiler doesn't really compete with gcc, or MSVC, not to mention something like Comeau or Intel that's based on the EDG front-end.

Comment: DJGPP, with its GCC 4.3 port, will do modern C++ just fine.

Comment: `When used in C++ programs, the standard C header files now make their contents visible in namespace std as well as in the global namespace` - cited from DJGPP website. Does it mean it support's namespaces ?

Comment: why not SDCC? It supports the 8086. Course, it's also not C++, but who needs that!? :)

Comment: @earlz:"who needs that?" From the tags applied, the original poster does.

Comment: I don't see anything about C++ in his actual post though.

Comment: @earlz:it's hard to say for sure -- the "string" at the end of the last piece of code *could* be a C++ string, but it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @Earlz Can you elaborate on your claim? I couldn't find any evidence of past or present 8086 support in [the only SDCC I found](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/)... though it does appear to be a good choice for a wide range of non-AVR, non-PIC microcontrollers (with PIC support in the works).

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to as "emulated console" has nothing to do with emulation or DOS. You probably are still generating 32/64-bit Windows executables, just using console subsystem.

Start by changing your compiler to one capable of generating 16-bit code. I'm pretty sure that [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) still supports 16-bit MZ target out of box. IIRC [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) too, but I'm not sure and don't know if it's still maintained.

Edit: about `gotoxy`, you could:

1. Use [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) and don't care what is uses internally (I think it's INT10, though)
2. Use [interrupt 0x10](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0087.htm) on your own
3. Write directly to the VGA memory at `0xB8000`

I've never actually developed for DOS, so I don't know which method would be considered the best. Third seems to be the fastest one, though.

Comment: DOS is 16-bit, so you'd need to use memory segmentation to address 0xB8000, which (as far as I know) requires dropping back to ASM

Comment: Third is pretty straightforward and definitely faster.  

A fourth option: IIRC the old Borland compilers had their own pretty good Curses-style UI libraries (which write directly to B800:0000 internally).

Comment: @Charlie: Again IIRC, you can do memory segmentation in C/C++ by casting 32-bit integers to far pointers.

Comment: Ahh, can you? Did not know this. Can you link to a pastebin showing that? It would definitely help me :)

Comment: I'm no expert on Borland's stack but the "pretty good Curses-style UI libraries" by Borland mentioned by @Porculus is probably [Turbo Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision) (a text-mode GUI toolkit), which was open-sourced and has been ported to DJGPP. [Downloads here](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/) and [instructions here](http://www.delorie.com/howto/djgpp/turbo-vision-howto.html).

Comment: @anonymouscoward C wouldn't be very useful if you needed ASM to access other segments. In 16-bit apps, the [`MK_FP` macro](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/mk_fp.html) can be used to generate a "far pointer" from a segment and offset... or DJGPP and OpenWatcom's `FLAT` memory model (ie. compiling against a DPMI extender like DOS/4GW) offer a 32-bit flat memory model in DOS. According to [Paul Hsieh's WATCOM C/C++ FAQ](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/watfaq.shtml), under the `FLAT` memory model, a pointer to VGA address space can be created with `(char *)(0x0A0000)`.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a glance here: [MinGW compile for MS DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268077/mingw-compile-for-ms-dos)

Basically, use DJCPP as the back end to Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I was used to use **DJGPP** to compile things under plain ms-dos.. [home page](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/).

It's a full free compiler suite that should still work seamlessly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gotoxy` from `conio.h` header that comes with DJGPP.

Answer (score 1):

use the **gotoxy from the conio.h** library. (dos friendly ;) )

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    gotoxy(5,5);
    printf("Printing at (5,5)");
}
```

Simple

[Also check Borland's documentation](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs240/conio.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell your compiler to target dos. I don't know how to do that, sorry, but maybe this will serve as a hint for googling...

Looking at the Code::Blocks website, it seems your IDE can support various compilers (GCC, MSVC++ and others). So first, figure out which compiler you are using. Then check that compilers documentation.

Once you know what compiler you are using, then you can rephrase (refine) your question - I'm sure someone here on stackoverflow will know.

According to [this thread](http://fixunix.com/ms-dos/534101-compiler-16-bit-dos.html), it seems the Open Watcom][2](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) compiler targets dos. Also, it is supported by your IDE (Code::Blocks).

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting, considering the fact that there's so much open source OS, the licensed and maybe unsupported DOS is still being used :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dos stub header in win32 exe that display this message when ran on pure dos. You should compile it with a dos compiler e.g turbo c or provide target plateform if DOS is among it in case code blocks. Its a software issue not hardware platform.

Answer (score 0):

[ia16-elf](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/subscription57091) hosted on Linux or Windows has GCC 6.2 to link .COM files. (It hosts on Mac using Winery and MinGW for a bash shell and extracting the windows archive).

Use DosBox (or Boxer on Mac), QEMU, VirtualBox for testing, not rebooting a real physical machine that you care about.