# compile C program to MS-DOS environment

Tags: c, compilation, dos, djgpp

i have a small program that uses 32bit object file, and i wish to run it under dos operating system. now, after searching i found [DJGPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268077/mingw-compile-for-ms-dos). 
is there a way to use DJGPP to compile my program to 16Bit dos executable format?
thanks in advance

Comment: ... what is this MS-DOS you speak of? hehe

Comment: You want to run 32-bit protected mode code from that object file on a 16-bit real mode operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645032/msdos-hello-world-exe/) related Stack Overflow question. It might help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage of a 32-bit processor (386 and above) to run 32-bit code under 16-bit DOS (using [DPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Protected_Mode_Interface)), then DJGPP is definitely the right tool. That is, it produces 16-bit dos executable files containing 32-bit code. For object format it uses 32-bit COFF.